# Condition in JQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

The company we are working for on a project asked us to automate a sales contract where given context will be printed. However some variables will be entered via keyboard. First we come up with the idea that they can fill a form before printing the 5 pages contract and get that form data and use it where it is necessary. However they wanted to see the whole contract and fill in the gaps if necessary. So my solution was like this example below.

> This is ACME Company and Stackoverflow Corp. sales form Responsible person _____ License No:______

This goes on like that. 5-6 blanks with ______ used and when operator click on them i changed them into inputs so the user can enter if necessary and when hits enter blanks will be replaced with input data.Code is below

HTML

```
<ol type="A">
   <li>Условия за плащане по ранни записвания: <i class='veriRengi'>20% 12/12/2016</i></li>
   <li>Капаро в размер на не по-малко от <i class='fillThis veriRengi' id='DepositPercent' onclick='alanDoldur(DepositPercent)'>_____</i> % на човек, съобразно условията на конкретната програма.
      <br>Резервация се прави само след заплащане на капарото.</br>
   </li>
   <li>Остатъкът в размер на <i class='fillThis veriRengi' id='RemainingPercent'>___________</i> % или съответния неизплатен процент в зависимост от плащането по т. 4.A и т. 4.A, съобразно условията
      <br>на конкретната програма се заплаща минимум <i class='veriRengi'>15</i> дни преди датата на отпътуване.</br>
   </li>
   <li>В случай, че сумата по т. B. не бъде заплатена в посоченият срок, резервацията се анулира и капарото остава в полза на ТУРОПЕРАТОРА като неустойка за претърпените от последния вреди. 
      Ако причината за анулиране на резервацията е в ТУРОПЕРИТОРЪТ и ПОТРЕБИТЕЛЯТ е изпълнил задълженията си по т.4.A и т. 4.B в предвидените срокове, ТУРОПЕРАТОРЪТ възстановява на ПОТРЕБИТЕЛЯ платените от последния суми заедно с неустойка в размер на платеното по т.4.A капаро.
   </li>
   <li>Резервацията се счита за валидна, само ако е потвърдена от ТУРОПЕРАТОРА в рамките на 48 часа. Ако не бъде потвърден първоначално заявеният хотел, ТУРОПЕРАТОРЪТ може да предложи на ПОТРЕБИТЕЛЯ други възможности за настаняване. В случай, че ПОТРЕБИТЕЛЯТ не приеме другите възможности той има право да му бъде възстановено заплатеното капаро.</li>
</ol>
```

Jquery/JS:

```
function alanDoldur(divName) {
var eskiBilgi=$(divName).text();
if(eskiBilgi != "_______" ){
$(divName).html("<input type='text' value='"+eskiBilgi+"'></input>");
}           
else
$(divName).html("<input type='text'></input>");
$(divName).children().focus();
$(divName).keypress(function (e) {
var key = e.which;
if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
{ var bilgi= $(divName).children().val();
var bilgiHidden=bilgi;
var isim=(divName.id);
var yeni ="hidden"+isim+"_id";
console.log(yeni);
if(bilgi == "")
{
bilgi="_______";
bilgiHidden="";
}
$(divName).html(bilgi);
$("#"+yeni).val(bilgiHidden);
console.log($("#"+yeni).val());
if(divName.id=="DepositPercent" && $.isNumeric(bilgi)){
bilgiHidden=100-bilgi;
$("#RemainingPercent").html(bilgiHidden);
$("#hiddenRemainingPercent_id").val(bilgiHidden);
}
return false;  
}
});
$(".fillThis *").click(function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
});
}
```

Now the question is i can not get that work with lost focus/blur feature like if key==enter or blur(not enter or simply blur obviously but you get the idea).Any ideas how can i make it work?
PS: divName is send by onclick. it sends the divName of blank's span

Comment: The `.children()` will return an HTMLCollection and not an Element of type input, doing some `console.log` on your variables would help finding the issue.

Comment: Please post your HTML and full jQuery. Also, why even have the blank spans? Why not just have the textbox there and style it so it looks like the underscores, "_________"?

Comment: @thednp code is so much more than this, this is just a glimps to give the idea

Comment: @RobScott it was my manager, he wanted this way, if it gets over my head i will add css to make it look like underscore only.

Comment: You should try to post some 'working' example so we can understand the context. We aren't telepathic after all.

Comment: Could we see your event handlers that use focus/blur?

Comment: @thednp i added some parts of html(it actually creates most of it from database) and better js

Comment: Why don't you create a code snipet? Everybody can click and experience the issue. We are also not from Matrix movies.

Comment: If you are referring to `if(eskiBilgi != "_______" ){` you can make it easier, simply see if the string has the `_` character `if (/\_/g.test(eskiBilgi)) {  }`

Answer (score 0):

I coded this for you:

```js
function keypress() {
  $('.mytext').keypress(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13) // the enter key code
    {
      var word = $(this).val();
      if (word == "") word = "______";
      $(this).parents('.hole').html("<span class='hole'>" + word + "</span>");
    }
  });
}

$('.hole').click(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "______") {
    $(this).html("<input class='mytext' type='text' name='myname' placeHolder='your text..'>");
    keypress();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  This is ACME Company and Stackoverflow Corp. sales form Responsible person <span class="hole">______</span> License No:<span class="hole">______</span>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1yx453fp/)

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.